# How add sharedpref into Retrofit interface

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I need to get the following URL with Retrofit, `mensajes.php?cel=NUMBER`, How i can do for add the **NUMBER** from *sharedpref*, in this case Will be `user.getCel ()`

My interface code with Retrofit is this:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("mensajes.php?cel=")
    Call<List<Message>> getInbox();
}
```

I noob, thnks for you help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the param as a query param:

```
public interface ApiInterface {

    @GET("mensajes.php")
    Call<List<Message>> getInbox(@Query("cel") String one);
}
```

And then pass the shared pref when you use it:

```
Call<List<Message>> call = api.getInbox(sharedPref.getString("PHONE_KEY"));
```